# NHibernate query with filter by timestamp field

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nhibernate

I have table with versioning field of type Timestmap. Now I'm trying to make a query with search by this field, but when I'm passing parameter in next way:

```
query.SetParameter("TimeStamp", lastTick, NHibernateUtil.Timestamp);
```

it pass it as DateTime to the sql query. Also tried NHibernateUtil.Binary, but nhibernate pass it as varbinary.

Comment: what is the type of `lastTick`?

Comment: it is 8 bytes array as specified at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NHibernate TimestampType specifies:

> This is almost the exact same type as the DateTime except it can be used
>   in the version column, stores it to the accuracy the database supports, 
>   and will default to the value of DateTime.Now if the value is null.

This type is simply not for use with the MS SQL type TIMESTAMP. In fact, that column type is deprecated:

> The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.
>
> [rowversion (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

You should use `NHibernateUtil.Binary` or `NHibernateUtil.BinaryBlob`.

Comment: Database is really old, that is why timestamp columns in it. Already tried Binary and BinaryBlob - both of them pass varbinary to the database and it not works.

Comment: The issue was in my query and not in converting byte array. NHibernateUtil.BinaryBlob works great, thank you.

Comment: @Mardok: Can you mark this as the answer, if this guided you to the solution?